# Estoy guardando bien mis archivos en la carpeta de ampps

Tags: php

Estoy guardando mis archivos php en la carpeta www dentro de la carpeta ampps, esta bien guardado?

Comment: esta pregunta difiere de usuarios ; te recomiendo mejorar la pregunta, por que esto depende el criterio del que te quiera ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa es la ruta por defecto de `ampps` para guardar los archivos `PHP`.
El `DocumentRoot` es:

```
C:/ampps/www
```

Esto lo tiene configurado en el archivo de configuración de `apache`. Lo puedes modificar si tu deseas, pero para iniciar **es correcto** mantener esa ruta por defecto.

Luego si quieres cambiar esta ruta puedes modificar esto por algo así por ejemplo:

```
D:/www
```

Así tus archivos estarían en otra partición.
Espero te ayude.

Saludos